# WPF ItemsControl -> ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, grid, itemscontrol, contentpresenter

I hope someone can help me with my `ItemsControl` Problem :)

I use a `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` as an `ItemsPanel` to Add/Remove `Column/RowDefinitions` in MVVM (and also the Cell Content)
this works fine, but when I try to add a `GridSplitter` the splitter is shown but he doesnt work. The reason is the `ItemsControl` adds a new `ContentPresenter` for each item...

Is there any way to replace the `ContentPresenter` with the `GridSplitter` Control when the `Type` of an item in the children property is typeof `SplitterVM` ??

I'm also trying to bind the `Splitters` on the `Grid` as an `DependencyProperty` but when I use `ItemsPanel` it doesn't work because I cannot add `Children` to the `Panel`...

Here is my code:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GridVM}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <view:LayoutGridControl Rows="{Binding Rows}"  Columns="{Binding Columns}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Model.RowIndex}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Model.ColumnIndex}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding Model.RowSpan}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding Model.ColumnSpan}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Found solution, simple added a dp to my Custom Grid and bind the children Property. ^^

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer as it may help someone else.

Comment: I need this too. Can you post a solution?